# How to write mypy-safe factory for getting a class instance based on required class attributes?

Tags: python, oop, mypy, factory-method, abstract-base-class

### Context

I'm using ABC to create a bunch of sub-classes like so:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class Person(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def person_name(self) -> str:
        pass


class Jason(Person):
    person_name = "jason"
    person_age = 23


class Sarah(Person):
    person_name = "sarah"
    person_age = 27
```

### My Goal

I'm need a factory-function which will take in a person name as input and return the correct person class based on the name. I need it to be able to scale for when I write many sub-classes, as well as being mypy-safe - that is to say that mypy will raise an error if I forget to add the class attribute `person_name`.

### What I've tried

Here is my current solution:

```py
def person_factory(input_person_name: str) -> Person:
    if input_person_name == Jason.person_name:
        return Jason()
    elif input_person_name == Sarah.person_name:
        return Sarah()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown Person: {input_person_name}")
```

This function works well because:

- It's clear in what it's doing
- It works with mypy. Meaning that **if I create a class and forget to add the `person_name` class attribute, mypy will raise an error**

However, I have one large issue with this function, which is that **it does not scale well.** At work, I will need to make a lot of these `Person` sub-classes, dozens, maybe hundreds in the future, and a very long chain of if/elif statements no longer looks like a good option.

So I wrote this (*The type-hint on line 2 is because mypy complains otherwise*):

```py
def person_factory(input_person_name: str) -> Person:
    person_classes: List[Type[Person]] = Person.__subclasses__()

    for person_class in person_classes:
        if input_person_name == person_class.person_name:
            return person_class()

    raise ValueError(f"Unknown Person: {input_person_name}")
```

While this solution scales perfectly, allowing me to have any number of sub-classes, it is a little less clear (not that big of a problem for me) and, more importantly, **it is not mypy-safe.** If I create a class and forget to add the `person_name` attribute, although my IDE picks it up, **mypy does not**.

### My Question

Is there a way to achieve my goal in Python? Am I missing something here? As this seems like a common pattern that would occur often in OOP, but I'm struggling to find anything that isn't just a bunch of if/elif, or a dictionary mapping (essentially the same thing).

Is there a way to dynamically determine the class to be created, without a large mapping object of some sorts, that will also work with static type checkers like mypy?

### Update

In response to the comments in my question, I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to achieve my goal. The real-world scenario that I'm working with is that I receive a list of strings, these strings which represent various "validations" that need to be run on some data. Each validation is essentially a function, so I decided to represent these validations by creating a class for each one.

This way I could enforce a `.validate()` method which allows me to iterate through a list of validation class-instances and validate each one. The problem is how do I map the list of strings to the validation classes themselves? (The strings are the names of the validations, retrieved from a spreadsheet originally).

Comment: I think the crux of the problem is that there is no way to force classes to implement a specific interface. ABCs and Protocols let you do that for class *instances*, but not classes themselves. If a class doesn't implement something, that's not a bug - that just means it's an abstract class. Which is why I'm pretty sure that mypy isn't the right tool for this.

Comment: To explain that in more detail: Mypy sees you access `person_class.person_name`, and it doesn't see a problem with that because every `Person` subclass *has* a `person_name` attribute. Because you defined it in `Person`. Sure, it's an `@abstractmethod`, but that doesn't matter, since you're not trying to call it on an instance. In this context, it's just a class attribute. Mypy knows that this attribute exists, so everything is fine. Mypy could only detect this as an error if you could specify that "every `Person` subclass must have a `person_name` attribute of type `str`".

Comment: I doubt that you can achieve this with `mypy`. However, many runtime solutions exist: you can write your own metaclass to check that during class creation - maybe inheriting from `ABCMeta` - or just add a test trying to instantiate all classes (`for person_class in Person.__subclasses__(): person_class()`).

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey and SUTerliakov - it's a shame it doesn't seem like there's a way to enforce this. I wonder if there's a different design pattern that allows me to have an expanding list of classes that can be dynamically instantiated :/